# Why does an SSL Server Socket connection block in Java whereas a non SSL Server Socket does not?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, sslsocketfactory

Consider the following code for a non-SSL Socket server and client all on the one thread:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(0); // open a random free port.

        Socket c = new Socket(ss.getInetAddress(), ss.getLocalPort());

        Socket s = ss.accept();

        final byte[] bytes = "Hello World!".getBytes();
        final OutputStream out = c.getOutputStream();
        System.out.println("writing to stream");
        out.write(bytes.length);
        out.write(bytes);

        System.out.println("reading from stream");

        final DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        int len = in.read();
        final byte[] b = new byte[len];
        in.readFully(b);
        System.out.println(new String(b));

        c.close();
        ss.close();
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
writing to stream
reading from stream
Hello World!
```

This process opened a server socket - connected with a client socket. Passed data down the socket and then closed down. There was no issue passing the data.

Consider a version to a prove a point with SSL Sockets:

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SSLServerClient {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("InfoLogging");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/path/KeyStore.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");

        SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();

        SSLServerSocket serverListeningSSLSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(4380);
        log.info("Server started");

        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory=(SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLSocket clientSocket =  (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(serverListeningSSLSocket.getInetAddress(),
                serverListeningSSLSocket.getLocalPort());

        SSLSocket serverCommsSSLSocket = (SSLSocket) serverListeningSSLSocket.accept();
        log.info("new client");

        final byte[] bytes = "Hello World!".getBytes();
        final OutputStream out = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        System.out.println("writing to stream");
        out.write(bytes.length);
        out.write(bytes);

        System.out.println("reading from stream");

        final DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(serverCommsSSLSocket.getInputStream());
        int len = in.read();
        final byte[] b = new byte[len];
        in.readFully(b);
        System.out.println(new String(b));

        clientSocket.close();
        serverCommsSSLSocket.close();
        serverListeningSSLSocket.close();
    }
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
Nov 21, 2018 10:23:51 PM com.gamble.ssl.SSLServerClient main INFO: Server started
Nov 21, 2018 10:23:52 PM com.gamble.ssl.SSLServerClient main INFO: new client
writing to stream
```

ie it blocks on the server socket starting.

My question is: **Why does an SSL Server Socket connection block in Java whereas a non SSL Server Socket does not?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to the question is:

> Because an SSL Handshake [is asynchronous](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#startHandshake()) and [the non SSL socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) doesn't have to do that step.

Ok - there were two issues with the original SSL Code:

1. There was no TrustStore:

   ```
   System.setProperty( "javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/path/KeyStore.jks");
   ```
2. Because the Handshake is synchronous - you have to start the client on a different thread. ie:

   ```
   (new Thread() {
     public void run() {
       // do stuff
     }
    }).start();
   ```

So the code looks like:

```
    import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket;
    import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;
    import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
    import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    public class SSLServerClient {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/path/KeyStore.jks");
            System.setProperty( "javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/path/KeyStore.jks");

            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");

            SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();

            SSLServerSocket serverListeningSSLSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(4380);
            System.out.println("--server started");

            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory=(SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLSocket clientSocket =  (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(serverListeningSSLSocket.getInetAddress(),
                    serverListeningSSLSocket.getLocalPort());

            SSLSocket serverCommsSSLSocket = (SSLSocket) serverListeningSSLSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("--new client");

            final byte[] bytes = "--Hello World!".getBytes();
            final OutputStream out = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            System.out.println("--Gotten output stream");
            final DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(serverCommsSSLSocket.getInputStream());

            (new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("--reading from stream");

                    int len = 0;
                    try {
                        len = in.read();
                        final byte[] b = new byte[len];
                        in.readFully(b);
                        System.out.println(new String(b));

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();


            System.out.println("--writing to stream");
            out.write(bytes.length);
            System.out.println("--writing to stream - length");
            out.write(bytes);

            clientSocket.close();
            serverCommsSSLSocket.close();
            serverListeningSSLSocket.close();
        }
    }
```

And the output looks like

```
    --server started
    --new client
    --Gotten output stream
    --writing to stream
    --reading from stream
    --writing to stream - length
    --Hello World!

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Done

(Note I added the leading `--` to the output to aid when reading SSL Debug output.

Answer (score 0):

What does "flip to plaintext?" mean?

Here's what you are doing:

- Creating an SSL server socket
- Creating a normal socket connected to the SSL server socket
- Sending some data from the client side
- Reading some data on the server side

Now, the SSL socket expects encrypted data transfer. But the data you are not sending is not encrypted, so it's not valid SSL and it throws an exception - as it says, "Unrecognized SSL message" because you are not sending a valid SSL message, and "plaintext connection?" is a hint about what might be wrong.

You have to use SSL on both sides of the connection, or they can't talk to each other properly.

Comment: Thanks for this comment - it is super helpful. I've updated the question.